# Make memoir actually double-spaced

Tags: spacing, memoir, line-spacing

My University requires double-spacing for dissertations.

The memoir documentation (pg. 50) says:

> ... the declaration `\DoubleSpacing` really doubles the spacing between lines which really looks bad; but if
> you have to use it, it is there.

The problem is that it doesn't - it looks like less than double-spaced, and when I put my PDF side-by-side with one published by another student I see that his paper (left side) has 23 lines per page while mine (and my test code shown on the right side) has 27:

[image: spacing comparison]

Here's my test document:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  letterpaper,
]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\DoubleSpacing

Line 1. This is a test document.\\
Line 2. This is a test document.\\
Line 3. This is a test document.\\
Line 4. This is a test document.\\
Line 5. This is a test document.\\
Line 6. This is a test document.\\
Line 7. This is a test document.\\
Line 8. This is a test document.\\
Line 9. This is a test document.\\
Line 10. This is a test document.\\
Line 11. This is a test document.\\
Line 12. This is a test document.\\
Line 13. This is a test document.\\
Line 14. This is a test document.\\
Line 15. This is a test document.\\
Line 16. This is a test document.\\
Line 17. This is a test document.\\
Line 18. This is a test document.\\
Line 19. This is a test document.\\
Line 20. This is a test document.\\
Line 21. This is a test document.\\
Line 22. This is a test document.\\
Line 23. This is a test document.\\
Line 24. This is a test document.\\
Line 25. This is a test document.\\
Line 26. This is a test document.\\
Line 27. This is a test document.\\
Line 28. This is a test document.\\
Line 29. This is a test document.\\
Line 30. This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

I found `memoir.cls` in my texlive installation, and I see this code in it:

```
\newcommand*{\@DoubleSpacing}{
  \setSpacing{1.667}% default (10pt)
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax   % 10pt
    \setSpacing{1.667}%
  \or%  11pt
    \setSpacing{1.618}%
  \or%  12pt
    \setSpacing{1.655}%
  \or\or% 14pt
    \setSpacing{1.60}%
  \or\or\or% 17pt
    \setSpacing{1.545}%
  \or\or% 9pt
    \setSpacing{1.8}%
  \else%       larger sizes
    \setSpacing{1.5}%
  \fi}
```

None of these numbers is actually `2`.

What is the proper way to get memoir to actually do double-spacing, as the manual claims it should do? (I suppose I can try using `\setSpacing{2.0}` directly instead of `\DoubleSpacing`, but I'm concerned that this might have other side effects because I don't know how it interacts with other parts of `memoir` and/or other packages. Would that be correct, or is there a better way to do it?)

Comment: Have you tried `\setSpacing{2}`?

Comment: I believe it is safe to use `setSpacing{2}`. Its definition merely defines `\baselinestretch`. I looked at `memoir.cls` in a plain text editor, and it seems to be used the way it should be used.

Comment: Memoir does double spacing if you tell it to do so. By default  it sets 1 inch = 72.27 inches; other programs may set 1 inch = 72 inches. Be very carefull when comparing PDF outputs as the programs may use different scaling factors.

Comment: @PeterWilson I know it sets the size differently - that's why programs like Adobe Acrobat say the font size is 11.96pt instead of 12pt. That has nothing to do with my problem. Using `\setSpacing{2}` makes my line spacing exactly the same as the sample document on the left side of the image above. If memoir "does double spacing if you tell it to do so", why does the code say that `\DoubleSpacing` uses line spacing between 1.5 and 1.667, depending on font size?

Comment: Different fonts in different sizes have different values for interline spacing. What is your possible proposal versus memoir's proposal?

Comment: @PeterWilson I think that if the documentation says "the declaration `\DoubleSpacing` really doubles the spacing" then it should act the same as actually doubling the spacing in other document classes. The whole reason this declaration exists is for compatibility with ridiculous requirements, but if you put it side by side with other documents that meet those requirements, it doesn't look the same.

Comment: I'm too old and it is too long ago. Have you checked the code for DoubleSpacing in the default LaTeX classes? I did my best to make `memoir` obey the regular typographic conventions. Again, what is your proposed (detailed) solution code?

Comment: The `memoir` class has been available for over 20 years. No one  else has complained about this. What are your suggestiions for solving your problem (apart from not using `memoir`)?